# How to prove $ - |x| \leqslant \sin x \leqslant |x|\quad,\quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, inequality

How to formally prove
$$ - |x| \leqslant \sin x \leqslant |x|\quad,\quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \; ?$$
without using derivatives and graphs of real functions.

Please, could anyone respond?

Thank you very much beforehand.
Greetings.

Comment: You can simplify your problem to proving that $-1 \leq \sin\,x \leq 1$... and due to periodicity and symmetry, you can in fact consider $x$ in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$...

Comment: Tried to look at its series expansion ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions

Comment: I do not think is appropriate series expansion
because it is a chapter belonging to the boundary

Comment: And then, what else is Mr. J.M.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a circle, radius 1, center $(0,0)$. Draw a radius making angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis, and meeting the circle at $(x,y)$. Then $\sin\theta$ is $y$, while $\theta$ is the length of the arc of the circle from $(x,y)$ to $(1,0)$. Argue from the picture that $\sin\theta\lt\theta$ for $\theta\gt0$. That should get you started.

Comment: Yes, it should be, thank you very much Gerry, that helped me. Greetings. : D